# ¿Es posible debuggear un proyecto de Visual Studio Code en el que sólo hay peticiones y respuestas?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, vscode

Ahora mismo me hallo inmerso en una aplicación que se basa sobre todo en geolocalización. Está realizada en typescript, y se basa en petición-respuesta. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código nos informa de si estamos en tierra o agua:

```
'use strict';

const router = require('express').Router();

let requireAuthentication = require('../../lib/requireAuthentication');

let Seacoast = require('../../models/Seacoast');

import {CustomError} from '../../lib/utils/customError';
import {buildSortObject} from '../../lib/utils/utils';

//Unificar métodos de test para pruebas

router.get('/checkIsLand/:lat/:lon', requireAuthentication(['panel']), checkIsLand);
export async function checkIsLand(req, res, next) {
  try {
    let options: any = {
      skip: req.query.skip ? parseInt(req.query.skip) : 0,
      limit: req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 1000,
      sort: buildSortObject(req.query.sort),
      fields: req.query.fields ? req.query.fields : ''
    };

    let noUpload = (req.query.noUpload === 'true');

    const polygon = await Seacoast.collection.findOne({
      land: {
        $geoIntersects: {
          $geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [parseFloat(req.params.lon), parseFloat(req.params.lat)]
          }
        }
      }
    }, {land: 1});

    let point: any;
    let upload: any;
    let isLand = polygon ? true : false;

    if (isLand) {
      if (!noUpload) {
        upload = await Seacoast.getDistanceUploadImage(req.params.lat, req.params.lon, options);
      }
    } else {
      point = await Seacoast.getPositionThrow(req.params.lat, req.params.lon, options, req.params.distance);
    }

    res.json({success: true, isLand: isLand, point: point, upload: upload});
  } catch (err) {
    next(new CustomError(err.name + ': ' + err.message));
  }
};

export {router};
```

Luego se realiza la petición correspondiente, usando el programa POSTMAN (por ejemplo), para realizar GET, POST, UPDATE....

Pero si la respuesta que recibimos no es la esperada, debido a un posible fallo o mala programación de nuestro código, ¿existe alguna manera de realizar un debuggeo?

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si claro, existe una forma de desarrollar que se llama Test Driven Development el cual hace exactamente lo que necesitas, el framework más usado para hacer estas pruebas se llama Jestjs.